# Is it possible to edit the inline code in with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am aware of the ability to edit text with beautifulsoup, is it possible to edit the href links? I would like to be able to take say `<a href="/foo/bar/">` and use beautifulsoup to change it to `<a href="http://www.foobarinc.com/foo/bar/">`. I am not sure how I would use beautifulsoup to do this? Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: You need to highlight your anchor tags with the "code" button (101010) so we can see them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in your other question: with BeautifulSoup you're parsing in the content to a set of hierarchically nested objects representing the document, then changing those objects before serialising them back to different text. You're not editing the text directly.

The `href="..."` part of the markup represents an attribute. To access the attributes of each element in BeautifulSoup you use the `el[name]` [item-style access](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20attributes%20of%20Tags). So to change rooted URLs into absolute ones in `a href` attributes, it's as simple as:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    if link['href'].startswith('/'):
        link['href']= 'http://www.foobarinc.com'+link['href']
```

Comment: I was trying similar things to that, but kept getting [none] returned. I cannot find a list of the dictionary that matches the tags. I tried this, and it returned KeyError:href.

Also, thanks a lot bobince.

Answer (score 3):

Despite what the OP says in a comment to bobince, the following code works just fine:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

ht = '''
  <a href="/foo/bar/">Hello world</a>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(ht)

for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    if link['href'].startswith('/'):
        link['href']= 'http://www.foobarinc.com'+link['href']
print soup
```

emits

```
<a href="http://www.foobarinc.com/foo/bar/">Hello world</a>
```

as desired.  So, instead of vaguely claiming

> I was trying similar things to that,
>   but kept getting [none] returned. I
>   cannot find a list of the dictionary
>   that matches the tags. I tried this,
>   and it returned KeyError:href.

(???), the OP had better try to modify the code I just posted, getting it closer and closer to his own, until the weird errors `[none] returned` and `KeyError:href` (???) appear: at that time, the very last change that made them appear should make it blatantly obvious what the OP is doing wrong -- if not, post the exact data and code, as I did, and the exactly copy-and-pasted traceback (**not** vague personal paraphrases!-), and I bet we'll be able to help!-)